# setPasswordAttribute problema para registar laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un formulario que permite al administrador crear usuarios, pero para que al momento de crearlo no lo guarde en la base de datos con sin encriptar uso este codigo

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;


     public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {   
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    } 

//Otros metodos..
```

El problema es que ahora, al un usuario registrarse en por el login por defecto que me provee laravel auth, no puede ingresar, dice que las crendenciales no son validas.

Comment: Cambia el bcrypt en el mutator por hash::make y remueve la encriptacion en el metodo register, estas encriptando un hash y por eso no hace el match

Answer (score 0):

La función `bcrypt` por debajo invoca al servicio de hashing especificando el algoritmo homónimo:

```
function bcrypt($value, $options = [])
{
    return app('hash')->driver('bcrypt')->make($value, $options);
}
```

Pero la gracia de tener resolución de bindings a nivel del container es que tú no necesitas saber cuál es el driver de hashing que se está usando. Le dices en cambio [que haga su magia como sea que deba resolver el mentado servicio](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#hashing-passwords).

```
    $password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
```

Efectivamente lo más probable es que se esté usando bcrypt, pero deja que sea problema suyo.

Tu administrador debiera ejecutar ese hashing una sola vez, al momento de crear al usuario. Por ejemplo en un `RegisterController` con un método `create`

```
/**
 * Crear usuario
 *
 * @param array $data (name, email, password)
 *
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Y eso no tocarlo nunca más. Si lo modificas en un mutator ¿Cómo te consta que el valor venga en texto plano?

Por mientras, puede que te resulte usar el método [needsRehash](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#determining-if-a-password-needs-to-be-rehashed), que no es exactamente para eso pero permite revisar si el texto tiene el formato de un hash con complejidad X. Un texto plano no pasará la prueba de blancura y entrará al if:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{   
  if (Hash::needsRehash($value)) {
    $value = Hash::make($value);
  }
  $this->attributes['password'] = $value;
}
```

Pero... insisto en que eso no debe ir en un mutator.